# Can't get flashdata to display after using Ion Auth logout() method

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm using Ion Auth with CodeIgniter and can't figure out how to get session data to display after using the logout method.

I have a logout method like this:

```
public function logout() {

    $this->ion_auth->logout();
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="has-success"><span class="help-block">Your password has been successfully changed. Please login to continue!</span></div>');
    redirect('users/login');

}
```

The method that is calling this is the change password method, I'm calling it like this:

```
if ($this->ion_auth->change_password($identity, $this->input->post('old_password'), $this->input->post('password'))) {
    $this->logout();
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="has-error"><span class="help-block">'.$this->ion_auth->errors().'</span></div><div class="has-error"><span class="help-blocK"></span></div>');
    redirect('users/change_password');
}
```

I'm echoing it as normal in my view on the login page as well:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
```

As soon as I remove the `$this->ion_auth->logout()` method everything works.

I know that the `logout()` method destroys the session so that's why I set the flashdata after, but when I redirect to the login page I'm still not getting the message. It seems like this is how it is setup in the github repo as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sever will not create session after destroying the session until a new request is made to the server. Simply create another function in your controller and after logout redirect to that function and set your flashdata in that function plus redirect it where you want.

**Example:**

```
public function logout() {
    if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        $this->ion_auth->logout();
        redirect(base_url() . 'front/logout_message', 'refresh');
    }
    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}

public function logout_message() {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully! Logged Out!');
    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because logout destroys the session and theres not a new session ready to use until the next refresh with the way CI handles sessions.

The code to note is here https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/libraries/Ion_auth.php#L417

Comment: Got it! Is there a way around this? Perhaps like redirecting twice, once to create the session, store the message, and then redirect again?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `unset_userdata` to keep your flashdata.

**use this function below to logout and keep flashdata:**

```
 function logout_with_flashdata(){
    $ci =& get_instance();
    foreach($ci->session->userdata as $k => $v){
      if($k == 'message' || $k == '__ci_vars'){
        continue;
      }
      $ci->session->unset_userdata($k);
    }
  }
```